# Display entire html file using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to develop an application using Spring Boot and AngularJS. The problem here is the HTML (Twitter Bootstrap 3) file is stored in DB. And I don't have any idea how to load/display this HTML file using AngularJS.

So far my AngularJS controller looks something like below:

```
myApp.controller('initCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    console.log('init ctrl');
    $scope.info= {};
    $scope.init= function(){
        console.log($scope.info);
        $http.post('load',$scope.info).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);//Getting Entire HTML file using Spring Controller from db
            //enter code here
        });
    };
});
```

I can't use `<div ng-include="{{template}}"></div>` as I can't include an entire HTML inside a `<div>` element. And the HTML file will be updated very frequently with `headers` and `footers`. So there is not much I can do with the HTML except to render it and display in the browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you already in the HTML scope !?

Comment: yes, but it's scope is different.

Comment: I don't see how you can put <html> inside an <html> so it'll work... you show inject the inner of the <body> somewhere inside the current body...

Comment: I don't want to keep the HTML inside an HTML. I want a separate HTML to display.

Comment: `$(html).find('body').html()`    Like this ??

Comment: No, I mean you know how traditional servelet works with HTML. The whole HTML code written inside the java code and then we display it on demand. This is very similar to that but here I am trying to achieve it using AngularJS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149227/discussion-between-satya-and-evgenykolyakov).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind HTML to div by using ng-bind-html

```
<div ng-show="htmlFlag" ng-bind-html="htmlData"></div>
```

### In your Controller:

```
myApp.controller('initCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    console.log('init ctrl');
    $scope.htmlFlag = false;
    $scope.info= {};
    $scope.init= function(){
        console.log($scope.info);
        $http.post('load',$scope.info).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.htmlFlag = false; 
            $scope.htmlData = response.data;
            $scope.htmlFlag = true;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I cant means you dont want to do this way, or your code is not working this way?

Comment: This will work. Whenever your HTML gets the change in the DB. You can see the effect directly on your page by reloading it.

Comment: I can't mean it's impossible to do using this approach as it is applicable to only for inner Html. But in my case, I have to load an entire HTML page not just a few lines or div.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple...

Here is your updated code.

**`Contoroller`**

```
myApp.controller('initCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    console.log('init ctrl');
    $scope.info= {};
    $scope.init= function(){
        console.log($scope.info);
        $http.post('load',$scope.info).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);//Getting Entire HTML file using Spring Controller from db
            $scope.renderHtml = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

**`HTML`**

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml"></div>
```

Comment: You should store only <body></body> part in the DB. And then render it inside a <div></div>

Comment: That's not up to me. It's different app who is going to update the db.